# Giving a datagridview row a background image in C#.net

Tags: c#, datagridview, background-image

I want to set an image as background for a datagridview but I can't find a property to do this.

Comment: Can you detail what king of grid are you using? WinForms, WebForms, .NET version etc

Comment: DataGridView in C#.net (WinForms)

Answer (score 1):

This should be closer to what you need

```
Image image;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\x.jpg");
}

private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}

private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, e.RowBounds);
}
```

Of course you can alternate images depending on your row index.
If it not enough let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the paint event of the datagridview.
like this:

```
    Image bgImage;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bgImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg");
    }

    private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bgImage, new Point(0, 0));
    }
```

Comment: This Code draws an image at the left corner of the page!But I want to give an image as a background for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You could give it a CSS Class or modify the theme's row Css Class (if you have one), to have a background property:

> .rowClass {    background: url('your file here') top left no-repeat; }